# Badge for no downvotes

Tags: feature-request, badge-request

I think getting no downvotes for an extended period should be recognised, for example:

- no downvotes for 25 consecutive answers: bronze
- no downvotes for 80 consecutive answers: silver
- no downvotes for 200 consecutive answers: gold

It would be a mark of quality of answers, rather than sheer quantity, which is how some make reputation.

#### Edit

Perhaps to stop a driveby downvote affecting the clean run, it could be "less than 1% of votes are down votes" or similar

Comment: Sounds like a cool badge to have, but if you've made it to 399  consecutive answers without any downvotes and then a drive by downvote spoils it all, it will be harsh.

Comment: Only 25 to go for your bronze.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Bad idea. I think this makes downvotes that much more negative, when we should encourage people to *care less* about them. Now downvotes can spoil your obtaining a gold badge?

Comment: Agreed. Down votes are to say this isn't very useful or may be wrong. Not to tell people "never post again" they are only a reminder for quality not quantity, Plus with the badges they can be turned into more negative "weapons" per say

Comment: Exactly. They're not punitive, they're simply meant to sort good content from bad content.

Answer (score 6):

The cynic in me sees it as troll-bait. This would be among the only circumstances I can think of where another user could actively and intentionally hinder your progress.  Rep-wise, a serial downvoter can only remove 2 points against 10 per upvote, and as soon as it becomes obvious enough, the audits will catch the behavior.

But it's trivial to look at a reputation history and target at just the right moment and wreck your "clean record" badge.

It sounds fun, but it also reminds me of the disappointments of flag weight - watching that graph go up and up, only to drop way back down.  That might actually encourage answerers to *delete good answers* if they receive a downvote among multiple upvotes (assuming deletion wipes the record), and that affects the whole community & wider Internet in the interest of rescuing a badge for the answerer.

Comment: That's not cynicism, it's *common sense*. The data explorer would even make it easy to look for likely targets (people with long strings of no downvotes historically).